# building video from images with ffmpeg w/ pause between frames

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I want a ffmpeg command to make a video out of `x` images with a `y` sec pause between frame change, so that one can actually see the image. Something like the below command seems close based on what I've read, but I can find out how to add the pause that I want..

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%01d-0.jpg -y test.mpg
```

Any idea how to add the pause?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution would be setting the input framerate to frames per second, and then manually setting the output framerate to something accepted by the codec. For example:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1 -i img%01d-0.jpg -y -r 25 test.mpg
```

This would lead to every image to be shown for one second. `-r 0.5` would mean 2 seconds and so on.

Comment: so the first frame appears to be there but only for a few ms and it can't be seen when playing the video real time because it's gone so fast.

Comment: ok things seem better when I make a copy of the first image and make that `img0.jpg` it kind of sucks to have to make a copy of the first frame though..

Comment: Interesting - it seems to omit this for the first frame. A workaround would be adding -itsoffset [seconds] before the -i, as this seems to do the trick for the first frame too.